# How to add context/bean config to JAXRSServerFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring, rest, cxf

I embeded my cxf in Spring,
however, my cxf REST service cannot autowire my DAO. Please help!

The cxf REST service is triggered by:

```
JAXRSServerFactoryBean sf = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
sf.setResourceClasses(CustomerService.class);
sf.setAddress("http://localhost:9000/");
sf.create();
```

In **serviceImpl.java**

```
@Autowired 
SomeDAO someDAO; 

public void getSomething() {
    someDAO.get(); // get NullPointerException
}
```

In **Appconfig.java**

```
@Bean
someBean someBean(){
  return new someBeanImpl();
}
```

I think the problem is that the **Appconfig.java** context doesnt get registered by JAXRSServerFactoryBean. So how can I add it?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem, just post my solution here to help others.

don't use "setResourceClasses(CustomerService.class);" when you use cxf emmeded in Spring!!! if the resource class is used in this way, the service bean is to be created out of the Spring context. So start the server follow this:

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
ctx.register(config.class);
ctx.refresh()

JAXRSServerFactoryBean sf = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
sf.setResourceClasses(ctx.getBean(CustomerService.class));    
// use service interafce if you have both implementation class and interface
// but make sure don't create/new a service class
// which is actually created out of your spring context
// therefore in that service, the @Autowired is not working

sf.setAddress("http://localhost:9000/");
sf.create();
```

Hope this helps others!